# Arrangement of objects in 2 intersecting circles

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can 8 tennis balls and 8 baseballs be arranged in 2 intersecting circles (much like on the perimeter of a Venn diagram), if there is a ball placed at each of the 2 intersections of the circle perimeters, 3 on each segment of circle perimeter inside the other circle, and 5 on the segment of perimeter outside the other circle? The points are equally spaced and rotations are not counted.

Now approaching this question is difficult. Should the balls be sorted into the circles first, or sorted to fit the 3 types of points described in the question?

Comment: How are rotations not counted? There isn't any rotation that will leave both circles globally invariant. Do you mean permuting the balls within each segment is not considered to make a difference? And if so, what about interchanging the balls at the two intersection points?

Comment: I meant no rotations as in no 180 degree rotation of the whole arrangement. Obviously rotation 1 of the circles will change the arrangement.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has pointed this out, but 3 on the inside and 5 on the outside actually gives 18 balls total, not 16.  You have $3 + 5 = 8$ from each circle not counting the intersection, so $8 \cdot 2 = 16$ total, and then $2$ more from the two intersections...could you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Split into cases.

Case 1: Balls on the intersection are both tennis balls (or baseballs).
Case 2: Balls on intersection are 1 tennis, 1 baseball.

In each case, it's easy to count the number of possibilities directly.

---

Case 1: Both balls are tennis balls. Then, the rest of the 14 balls must be arranged in some order. Ignoring the restriction about rotation, there are ${14 \choose 8} $ ways to do so. Now, we account for rotation. Generally, the rotated version will be different (and hence we would have double counted), except when it is symmetrical. There are ${ 7 \choose 4} $ ways which are symmetrical (basically once you decide which 4 balls remaining in the 'left' circle are baseballs).

Hence, there are $ \frac{ {14 \choose 8} + { 7 \choose 4} } { 2}  $ ways.

Case 1b: Both balls are baseballs. Then, there are $\frac {{14 \choose 8} + { 7 \choose 4} } {2} $ ways.

Case 2: One ball is a tennis ball, one is a baseball. WLOG, let the 'top' ball be a tennis ball. Then, there are ${14 \choose 7} $ ways to arrange the rest of the balls. Note that each of these ways are not rotations of each other, since the 'top' ball is a tennis ball.

Hence, there are $ { 14 \choose 8} + {7 \choose 4} + { 14 \choose 7} $ ways to arrange this.

Comment: The casework is unnecessary.  The difficulty here is dealing with the $180^\circ$ rotation; otherwise the answer would simply be $\frac{16!}{8!8!}$.  Casework does nothing to alleviate this difficulty.

Comment: @Goos I've expanded on my answer. Casework makes the rotation easier to deal with and account for.